# JNI crate. How pass -XstartOnFirstThread option to jvm?

Tags: macos, rust, java-native-interface

I need to add the "-XstartOnFirstThread" option to the JavaVM arguments in order to display the GUI on MacOs (Without this option, the application starts without errors, but does not display the GUI). On Linux and Windows without this option everything works fine. It is only needed for MacOs.
When I add it to the list of options I get the error:

```
Unrecognized option: -XstartOnFirstThread
thread 'main' panicked at src/main.rs:39:6:
Failed to create JavaVM: Create(JniCall(Unknown))
```

How can I add it to the JVM? After all, without it, my application does not work correctly on MacOs (the application window is not created)

The code I use to initialize and start the JVM:

```rust
let jvm_args = InitArgsBuilder::new()
        .version(JNIVersion::V8)
        .option("-XstartOnFirstThread") // This option need for run GUI on MacOs
        //Classpath with natives skipped 
        .build()
        .unwrap();
    let jvm = JavaVM::new(jvm_args)
        .expect("Failed to create JavaVM");
    let mut env = jvm
        .attach_current_thread()
        .expect("Failed to attach JNIEnv");
    //Java class find and invoke static method Main skipped.
```

I spent several hours searching for answers on google and reading the documentation, but I still couldn’t find an answer, has anyone encountered this problem or have any ideas?

Comment: Does `java -XstartOnFirstThread` work on the terminal?

Comment: Yes, in terminal everything works fine

Comment: I would first check if the `jni` crate finds the same JVM as you have on your terminal. It uses the [`java-locator`](https://crates.io/crates/java-locator) crate beneath the hood. Does the output of the sample program there match your expectations?

Comment: @Botje yes, they use the same versions, just in case, I also tried to create a JVM instance not using the JavaVM:new() method, but using the JavaVM::with_libjvm() method, specifying the path to the jvm library explicitly

Comment: @user207421 unless you have a reason to believe otherwise it would usually mean the [crate named `jni`](https://crates.io/crates/jni)

Comment: Does it work if you set [`ignore_unrecognized`](https://docs.rs/jni/latest/jni/struct.InitArgsBuilder.html#method.ignore_unrecognized) to `true`?

Answer (score 2):

After some investigation, it turns out that `-XstartOnFirstThread` is implemented in something called ["libjli"](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/80ccc989a892e4d9f4e2c9395a100cfabbdcda64/src/java.base/macosx/native/libjli/java_md_macosx.m#L918), not libjvm. The `java` executable links against libjli, whereas rust-jni uses libjvm as it normally should.

I managed to hack together the following code that uses the JLI_Launch function to start a Java interpreter. It launches the JVM on the main thread as you requested. You can verify this by setting `_JAVA_LAUNCHER_DEBUG=1`.

```
fn main() {
    let args = ["java", "-cp", ".", "-XstartOnFirstThread", "Test"];
    unsafe {
        let str_libjli = OsStr::new("/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-21.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/libjli.dylib");
        let libjli = Library::new(str_libjli).unwrap();
        let jli_launch: Symbol<unsafe extern fn(c_int, *const *mut i8, c_int, *const *mut i8, c_int, *const *mut i8, *const i8, *const i8, *const i8, *const i8, c_int, c_int, c_int, c_int) -> sys::jint> =
            libjli.get(b"JLI_Launch\0").unwrap();
        let args_as_cstr : Vec<*mut i8> = args.into_iter().map(|s| CString::new(s).unwrap().into_raw()).collect();
        let empty = CString::new("").unwrap();
        let java = CString::new("java").unwrap();
        jli_launch(args_as_cstr.len() as i32, args_as_cstr.as_ptr(), 0, null_mut(), 0, null_mut(), empty.as_ptr(), empty.as_ptr(), java.as_ptr(), java.as_ptr(), 0, 0, 0 ,0);
    }
    let args = ["java", "-cp", ".", "-XstartOnFirstThread", "Test"];
    unsafe {
        let str_libjli = OsStr::new("/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-21.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/libjli.dylib");
        let libjli = Library::new(str_libjli).unwrap();
        let jli_launch: Symbol<unsafe extern fn(c_int, *const *mut i8, c_int, *const *mut i8, c_int, *const *mut i8, *const i8, *const i8, *const i8, *const i8, c_int, c_int, c_int, c_int) -> sys::jint> =
            libjli.get(b"JLI_Launch\0").unwrap();
        let args_as_cstr : Vec<*mut i8> = args.into_iter().map(|s| CString::new(s).unwrap().into_raw()).collect();
        let empty = CString::new("").unwrap();
        let java = CString::new("java").unwrap();
        jli_launch(args_as_cstr.len() as i32, args_as_cstr.as_ptr(), 0, null_mut(), 0, null_mut(), empty.as_ptr(), empty.as_ptr(), java.as_ptr(), java.as_ptr(), 0, 0, 0 ,0);
    }
    let args = ["java", "-cp", ".", "-XstartOnFirstThread", "Test"];
    unsafe {
        let str_libjli = OsStr::new("/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-21.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/libjli.dylib");
        let libjli = Library::new(str_libjli).unwrap();
        let jli_launch: Symbol<unsafe extern fn(c_int, *const *mut i8, c_int, *const *mut i8, c_int, *const *mut i8, *const i8, *const i8, *const i8, *const i8, c_int, c_int, c_int, c_int) -> sys::jint> =
            libjli.get(b"JLI_Launch\0").unwrap();
        let args_as_cstr : Vec<*mut i8> = args.into_iter().map(|s| CString::new(s).unwrap().into_raw()).collect();
        let empty = CString::new("").unwrap();
        let java = CString::new("java").unwrap();
        jli_launch(args_as_cstr.len() as i32, args_as_cstr.as_ptr(), 0, null_mut(), 0, null_mut(), empty.as_ptr(), empty.as_ptr(), java.as_ptr(), java.as_ptr(), 0, 0, 0 ,0);
    }
    // Program never gets here
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried calling libjli instead of libjvm, but the result is the same. The only output I get is this:
```
WARNING in native method: JNI call made without checking exceptions when required to from CallStaticObjectMethod at org.lwjgl.opengl.MacOSXDisplay.nCreateWindow(Native Method) at org.lwjgl.opengl.MacOSXDisplay.createWindow(MacOSXDisplay.java:158)
at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.createWindow(Display.java:306)
at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:848)
- locked <0x0000000776fd2e28> (a java.lang.Object)
at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:757)
```

Comment: @SamanthaEvans I updated my answer with something that looks like it works. No idea if it is workable for your situation though...